# Increasing RAM capacity of laptop

Tags: memory

I am using HP Notebook series laptop (Model- 15bg002AU) (Windows 10 pre-installed) and current RAM installed is **4GB** and system architecture is *64bit*. I want to increase my laptop's RAM capacity.

How can I know the extendable RAM capacity of my laptop?

Comment: I think you need to know the specific product number of your notebook: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00820047

Comment: It looks like you can according to this foum post: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/RAM-upgrade-for-HP-15bg002au/td-p/5821393

Comment: @mkingsbu this was helpful1☺

Comment: Might want to ask on the HP forums of call up somewhere.  The person responding wasn't an official HP rep.  Part of the reason you pay so much for a branded laptop is support like that afterall!

Comment: @mkingsbu - Considering the laptop already comes with 4 GB, and the solution by that user was to purchase a 4 GB module, it means the user who suggested the module that would work has absutely no idea what they are talking about.  There isn't a way to add another moduel on top of the already (what is likely a soldered module) memory contained in the laptop in question.

Comment: @Ramhound: The image shown is that of a SODIMM slot, not soldered. Still, if the single slot has a 4GB SODIMM already, and no support for 8 GB SODIMM's, then it's indeed end of story.

Comment: I missed the image, saw it about 10 times, the specifications are clear though.  I see no evidence it supports more then 4 GB.

Comment: Your question is off topic due to your second question. I suggest you remove the bit about Android emulator

Answer (score 1):

The `HP 15-BG002AU` does not have expandable memory.

[image]

Source: [HP 15-BG002AU (Z1D89PA) NOTEBOOK](http://www.bestbudgetprice.com/hp-15-bg002au-z1d89pa-notebook/)

The [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04886216) is for *any* `HP 15 Notebook PC` which would include the device you have.  This does not mean that, your device, supports every possible configuration listed.

Based on: [HP 15-g002au compatible upgrades](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/HP-Compaq/hp-15-g002au) the maximum memory supported is 8 GB.

However, it has the footnote which states that the maximum is limited by the fact, you cannot exceed the manufacturer supported memory.  It also indicates there is only one memory bank, this means your device is only capable of a single memory channel, which means it would only support a single 2 GB, 4 GB or 8 GB capacity module.

However, the reason I suspect your device only supports 4 GB, is because a similar device [HP-BG004AU](http://www.bestbudgetprice.com/hp-15-bg004au-1df03pa-notebook/) seems to specifically indicate support for higher capacity modules.

> How can I know the extendable RAM capacity of my laptop?

You can trust that Crucial wants your return business, so purchase the memory from them, and take them at their guarantee it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The [15-g002au manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04886216) says on page 1 that your maximum RAM is 8 GB :

> 1 customer-accessible/upgradable memory module slot
>   Supports single-channel memory
>   DDR3L-1600-MHz Single Channel Support
>   DDR3L-1333-MHz Single Channel Support (DDR3-1600 downgrade to DDR3-1333)
>   Supports up to 8 GB of system RAM in the following configurations:
>   
>   - 8192-MB total system memory (8192×1) or (4096×2)

To be absolutely sure, I would suggest to download and run the
[Crucial System Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/) and see what it says about memory upgrades
and possible configurations. In my experience this tool is absolutely
trustworthy.

Without running the tool, the [Crucial website](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/HP-Compaq/hp-15-g002au) for your model offers these
sticks, where you can apparently choose between
either two 4 GB sticks or one 8 GB stick :

[image]

Comment: I don't doubt your information.  But the quote itself is confusing.  If the device has, "1 customer-accessible/upgradable memory module slot", then how can it support 2 4GB modules?  I think what is most likely is the case, this manual, is used for multiple *different(* variations of the same model.  In my research I found a 04 model that DID support 8GB because it DID support 2 modules.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know if it applies to this particular laptop but I have seen several HP laptops that have 1 SO-DIMM slot on each side of the motherboard. 1 is inaccessible for the user (not really inaccessible but it isn't for the faint of heart to disassemble the laptop that far) and has a 4 GB module factory installed. The other slot can be reached easily and is empty.

Comment: That's why I suggest running the Crucial System Scanner. After running Crucial and before deciding, I would suggest to the poster to open it up and see what are the possibilities. If it's beyond his expertise, a workshop might be required for the installation. If @Tonny's supposition is correct, then the most that can be done is probably to add 4 GB.